# Activity crashes because of Intent with ACTION_SEND

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parcel

I have an Intent to share a image from an view. It works, but once I canceled it to upload it on Instagram and I received an exception.

Google didn't help...

**Intent**

```
if(!getStringName().equals(" ")) {//check if it is usefull
        LinearLayout table=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_linear);
        table.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = table.getDrawingCache();
        String imagepath=saveBitmap(bitmap);
        //sv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        Intent shareImage=new Intent();
        shareImage.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareImage.setType("image/png");
        shareImage.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.app_name));
        shareImage.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getStringName());
        shareImage.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(imagepath)));
        startActivity(shareImage);
        //new RalaAlertToast(context, getString(R.string.share_success), false);
    }else {
        //show message, that it's not useful
    }
```

**Stack Trace**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{at.ralaweb.ralaprogramme.subnetztabelle/at.ralaweb.ralaprogramme.subnetztabelle.ActivityMain}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@41f7d760: Unmarshalling unknown type code 2131558402 at offset 200
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2227)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2276)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@41f7d760: Unmarshalling unknown type code 2131558402 at offset 200
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2080)
at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2363)
at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:1735)
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2070)
at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2314)
at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249)
at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:1273)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1794)
at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:948)
at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:920)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1138)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
... 12 more
```

**another thing: should I disable the drawing cache after the export?**

Comment: Do you have any classes in your code that implement the `Parcelable` interface? It looks like you do, and you have a bug in the way that your parcel and unparcel that class.

Comment: seems so, but I don't know which

Comment: I would do a search for "implements Parcelable" and look through those classes. Make sure that you are reading from the Parcel in the same order in which you write to the Parcel.

Comment: parcelable in _my project_: android-support-v4.jar android.jar libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar -> I think I can do less against it

Comment: should I disable the drawing cache?

Comment: This doesn't look remotely related to the drawing cache. If none of your classes implement the `Parcelable` interface, then it might be a bug with a library that you are using.

Comment: i know, thx - i think i can't solve the problem; but at the bottom is an other question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60254/discussion-between-rala-and-tanis-7x).